# How do I display data basing on the permissions a user has within a group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

In a custom module I wrote, I implemented `hook_og_permission()` to define a new group permission.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_og_permission().
 */
function logic_board_og_permission() {
  return array(
    'rulesprm' => array(
      'title' => t('Rules Form Perm'), 
      'description' => t("Allow og user to fill form"),
    ),
  );
}
```

I then use the following code to verify the user has that permission, to show some data.

```php
if (user_access('rulesprm')) {
  // …
}
```

The code doesn't work. Even if the user has that permission, the code inside the `if()` block isn't executed. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

`user_access()` is for core permissions, those added through `hook_permission()`. For organic groups own permissions hook, you need to use the complementary `og_user_access()`.

```php
if (og_user_access($group_type, $gid, 'rulesprm')) {
  // …
}
```

See the documentation comment for [`hook_og_access()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/og/-/blob/7.x-2.x/og.api.php#L38) given in the *og.api.php*  file, which states:

> Permissions are checked using `og_user_access()`.