# How do I check Organic Groups group permissions from a custom module?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I'm trying to show or hide a button based on if a user has permission to post content to a group or not, but I don't seem to be able to call the `og_user_access` function from my custom module.

I've tried calling it directly while loading the module file:

```
module_load_include('module', 'og'); 
$allowed = og_user_access('group', $group->nid, 'create resource content');
```

Doing this crashes the page with no Apache error just a watchdog error of:

> Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in entity_get_controller() (line 8066 of /data/home/rsdev/www/content/lnsres.rsdev.ca/web/includes/common.inc).

I've also tried using `module_invoke` like so:

```
$allowed = module_invoke('og', 'og_user_access', 'group', $group->nid, 'create resource content');
```

Calling the module like this doesn't crash the page, but it also doesn't return anything and if I add some `dpm()` calls in the contrib module function I notice it's not even being called. Doing some reading about `module_invoke` appears like it's mostly used to call hooks, which I don't think `og_user_access` is, so I'm not sure if that's even the correct path to take.

How should I check group permissions in OG from my custom module's code ?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [Display data basing on the group permission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256031/display-data-basing-on-the-group-permission)
because I'm not trying to use a permission I created. Also the only answer in that question doesn't work for me because as I explained, I can't call `og_user_access` without an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display data basing on the group permission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256031/display-data-basing-on-the-group-permission)

Comment: I think Clive's answer there could be clarified to define what `$group_type` is because it may not be clear. `$group_type` means "group entity type", not "bundle". If that helps you please update (if you have enough karma) the answer there.

Comment: @mradcliffe changing the $group_type variable from 'group' to 'node' didn't change anything. I don't know if this is necessarily a duplicate but the answer given in that question also doesn't work for me like I said in the description of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your group entity is a node which I'm guessing it should be change your code to:

```
$gid // your group's node id.
$allowed = og_user_access('node', $gid, 'create resource content');
```

Comment: I thought I had tried using 'node' before with the same parameters, but apparently hadn't. This fixed my issue !